# Обращение к элементу массива в строке PHP

Tags: php

Как можем обратиться к элементу массива в строке:

```
<?php
    $array = array("first" => 1, "second" => 2, "third" => 3); 
    echo "Это $array[first] элемент массива\n";       /// #1
    echo "Это {$array["second"]} элемент массива\n";  /// #2
    echo "Это ".$array["third"]." элемент массива\n"; /// #3
?>
```

Интересует следующее:

Почему когда мы обращаемся к первому элементу массива мы не обрамляем его хотя бы одинарными кавычками? (#1)

Понятно почему вне строки мы используем кавычки для обращения к элементу массива - т.к если бы их не было, была бы синтаксическая ошибка по поводу не существующей константы (Это относится что к #2 что к #3)

Comment: В первом случае, может, вся строка итак string, поэтому обрамление кавычками не требуется

Comment: @Doofy хотелось бы услышать более аргументированный ответ

Comment: Мне тоже, поэтому плюсь

Comment: @Doofy Ну у меня у самого есть предположение почему не нужно: кажись все дело в том, что мы не можем обратиться к константе из строки, поэтому интерпретатор автоматически понимает, что константы в данном контексте быть не может и понимает как строковый ключ массива
P.S Но это лишь догадки из мною вышесказанного текста

Answer (score 3):

Ответ надо искать в документации не на строки, а на массивы:

> Замечание: Повторим, внутри строки (string), заключенной в двойные кавычки, корректно не окружать индексы массива кавычками, поэтому "$foo[bar]" является верной записью.

Объяснения, впрочем там тоже нет, но хотя бы есть прямое указание на корректность синтаксиса.

Когда-то объяснение там было, но, видимо, снесли, как высосанное из пальца. И наиболее аднкватным ответом будет "тут так заведено".

Comment: Очень странно, что нету объяснения, а ведь так хотелось узнать причину такого написания (да кстати я там тоже читал)

Answer (score 0):

> Если интерпретатор встречает знак доллара ($), он захватывает так много символов, сколько возможно, чтобы сформировать правильное имя переменной. Если вы хотите точно определить конец имени, заключайте имя переменной в фигурные скобки.

...

> Аналогично могут быть обработаны элемент массива (array) или свойство объекта (object). В индексах массива закрывающая квадратная скобка (]) обозначает конец определения индекса. Для свойств объекта применяются те же правила, что и для простых переменных.

```
<?php
$juices = array("apple", "orange", "koolaid1" => "purple");

echo "He drank some $juices[0] juice.".PHP_EOL;
echo "He drank some $juices[1] juice.".PHP_EOL;
echo "He drank some $juices[koolaid1] juice.".PHP_EOL;
```

Взято c [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).
Там же ответы на простую и сложную обработку выражений, которые, надеюсь, будут так же полезны.

Comment: Я читал мануал! AHTUNG!
Но там не написано о том почему не нужно обрамлять ключ элемента массива кавычками! Ткните мне пальцем в этом мануале где будет объяснено!

Comment: @MaximPro, **В индексах массива закрывающая квадратная скобка (]) обозначает конец определения индекса.** То?

Comment: @Other не то. она не говорит почему ключ массива нельзя заключать   даже в одинарные кавычки внутри строки..ибо будет ошибка парсинга.. вот о чем автор спрашивает

Comment: @MaximPro, она, всмысле документация

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а разве это не очевидно? Раз ищется именно `]`, значит всё остальное трактуется как ключ. Правда урезанно, только "**expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)**". Желаете взять ключ типа `$arr['"']` - используйте сложную обработку (та, что в фигурных скобках).

Comment: @Other конечно не очевидно. Отсюда и вопрос автора))  и если написать `$arr = ["'first'" => "привет"];

echo "test $arr['first'] test2";` то ошибка сохранится... то есть я сделал ключом `'first'` а ошибка осталась)) так что какие тут могут быть очевидности?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а вроде очевидно. Используется **простой** синтаксис. Т. е. хочешь полноценное выражение с блекджеком и кавычками - включай **сложный**, через фигурные скобки. А если в целом - эта ситуация очень похожа на те особенности языков, которые одни считают багом, другие фичей, а на деле - исторически сложилось.